# How can I add a test-environment route dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i would like to add a route that is only available in test environment, so i would prefer not to pollute routes.rb file. i cannot seem to find a working way to add a route dynamically after original routes were drawn. i tried this https://gist.github.com/1351762 but that didn't quite work

How can I add a new route after routes.rb has already loaded and processed all the routes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [with_routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html#method-i-with_routing) test helper redefines routes within a block.

```
 with_routing do |map|
   map.draw do
    resources :test, only: [:show]
   end

   get :show
   assert assigns(:test)
 end
```

Comment: How do you clear this route?

Answer (score 3):

After some tries and errors, I found that:

```
Rails.application.routes.eval_block(Proc.new do                                                                             
  get "/backdoor", :to => "backdoors#backdoor"                                                                         
end)
```